# Why Does The Selector Not Change The Element?

Tags: html, css

Following the selector rules, when checking whether the checkbox is checked, the ~ selector should apply display: none; in the span elements, but this is not happening.

both the input has the same parent element
and spans are preceded by input.

Because it does not work?

https://codepen.io/fx-hunter/pen/MWBaPBW?editors=1100

I tried this

```css
.wrapper .content-input .botao:checked~.wrapper .content-input span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content-input">
    <input class="botao" type="checkbox" />
    <span>off</span>
    <span>on</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using `~` selector with intention of getting the ancestor but `~` selector is to get sibling of previous selector.

To fix this use

```
.wrapper .content-input .botao:checked ~ span {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado ! funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 1):

The two sequences share the same parent in the document tree, so there's no need to call the `span` by saying `.wrapper .content-input span`. Just saying `span` works fine!

```
.wrapper .content-input .botao:checked ~ span {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado ! funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 0):

Its working but you are targetting elements wrong. So, its causing the issue.

```css
/*
.botao:checked {
  display: none;
}
*/

.botao:checked ~ span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content-input">
    <input class="botao" type="checkbox">
    <span>off</span>
    <span>on</span>
  </div>
</div>
```